# Django Subdomains using django-subdomains package

Tags: python, django, subdomain, middleware

I am using the [django-subdomains package](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to create subdomains. The problem is that no matter how I configure the SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS, the site always directs to whatever I have put in ROOT_URLCONF as a default. Any insight as to what I am doing incorrectly would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Added MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

**mysite/settings.py**

```
...

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'subdomains.middleware.SubdomainURLRoutingMiddleware',
)

...

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS = {
    None: 'mysite.urls',
    'www': 'mysite.urls',
    'myapp': 'myapptwo.test',
}

...
```

**mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from myapp import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**myapp/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(Request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world.")
```

**myapptwo/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from myapptwo import views
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**myapptwo/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(Request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world. This is the myapptwo subdomain!")
```

Comment: did you add `subdomains.middleware.SubdomainURLRoutingMiddleware` to your middlewares config?

Comment: Yes, I do have that inside of my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Comment: What is 'myapptwo.test'? Try with 'myapptwo.urls'. The subdomain needs to be pointed to the url configuration for each subdomain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the [django-subdomains docs](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#quick-start) the subdomain middleware should come before CommonMiddleware

> Add subdomains.middleware.SubdomainURLRoutingMiddleware to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in your Django settings file. If you are using django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware, the subdomain middleware should come before CommonMiddleware.

so your settings should look like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'subdomains.middleware.SubdomainURLRoutingMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```