# django subdomains - SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS

Tags: python, django, subdomain

I am reading about [this django-subdomains middleware](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

I want to set language codes as subdomains like:

```
de.mysite.com
en.mysite.com
```

I added subdomains middleware before common middleware.

but I dont understand why and how I should use `SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS` config for this purpose..

any guidance would be very cool!

Comment: Were you able to get it sorted out?

Comment: @Gelbander yep, I just left out `SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS` and it worked :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Subdomains using django-subdomains package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493297/django-subdomains-using-django-subdomains-package)